# FFT-less $O(n\log n)$ algorithm for pairwise sums

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, fourier-transform

Suppose we are given $n$ distinct integers $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$, such that $0 \le a_i \le kn$ for some constant $k \gt 0$, and for all $i$.

We are interested in finding the counts of all the possible pairwise sums $S_{ij} = a_i + a_j$. ($i = j$ is allowed).

One algorithm is to construct the polynomial $P(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} x^{a_j}$ of degree $\le kn$, and compute its square using the Fourier transform method and read off the powers with their coefficients in the resulting polynomial. This is an $O(n \log n)$ time algorithm.

I have two questions:

- Is there an $O(n \log n)$ algorithm which does not use FFT?
- Are better algorithms known (i.e $o(n \log n)$)? (FFT allowed).

Comment: Why is it important to not use FFT?  It sounds like you already have a good solution to your problem.  Where does the requirement to not use FFT come from?  That sounds to me like a rather un-natural requirement to impose.

Comment: @D.W.: Because then there won't be a question to ask? :-) I am just curious to know if there is a different approach.

Comment: OK, got it!  I admit I am curious too. :-)  Thank you for the interesting question.

Comment: @D.W.: You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would seem that this problem is equivalent to integer/polynomial squaring:

**1.** **It is known that polynomial multiplication is equivalent to integer multiplication**.

**2.** Obviously, you already reduced the problem to polynomial/integer squaring; **therefore this problem is at most as hard as squaring.**

Now I will reduce integer squaring to this problem:

Suppose you had an algorithm:

$$
F(\mathbf{\vec a})\rightarrow P^2(x),\\
\text{where } P(x)=\sum_{a_i \in \mathbf{\vec a}} x^{a_i}
$$

This algorithm is essentially the algorithm you request in your question. Thus, if I had a magic algorithm that can do this, I can make a function, ${\rm S{\small QUARE}}\left(y\right)$ that will square the integer $y$ (**oh yes, I do love mathjax :P**):

$$
\begin{array}{rlr}\hline
&\mathbf{\text{Algorithm 1}} \text{ Squaring}&\hspace{2em}&\\
\hline
{\tiny 1.:}&\mathbf {\text{procedure }} {\rm S{\small QUARE}}\left(y\right):\\
{\tiny 2.:}&\hspace{2em}\mathbf {\vec a} \leftarrow ()
  &&\triangleright~\mathbf {\vec a}\text{ starts as empty polynomial sequence}\\
{\tiny 3.:}&\hspace{2em}i \leftarrow 0\\
{\tiny 4.:}&\hspace{2em}\mathbf{while}~y\ne0~\mathbf{do}
  &&\triangleright~\text{break }y\text{ down into a polynomial of base }2\\
{\tiny 5.:}&\hspace{4em}\mathbf{if}~y~\&~1~\mathbf{then}
  &&\triangleright~\text{if lsb of }y\text{ is set}\\
{\tiny 6.:}&\hspace{6em}\mathbf{\vec a} \leftarrow \mathbf{\vec a}i
  &&\triangleright~\text{append }i\text{ to }\mathbf{\vec a}~\text{(appending }x^i\text{)}\\
{\tiny 7.:}&\hspace{4em}\mathbf{end~if}\\
{\tiny 8.:}&\hspace{4em}i \leftarrow i + 1\\
{\tiny 9.:}&\hspace{4em}y \leftarrow y \gg 1
  &&\triangleright~\text{shift }y\text{ right by one}\\
{\tiny 10.:}&\hspace{2em}\mathbf{end~while}\\
{\tiny 11.:}&\hspace{2em}P^2(x) \leftarrow F\left(\mathbf{\vec a}\right)
  &&\triangleright~\text{obtain the squared polynomial via } F\left(\mathbf{\vec a}\right)\\
{\tiny 12.:}&\hspace{2em}\mathbf{return}~P^2(2)
  &&\triangleright~\text{simply sum up the polynomial}\\
{\tiny 13.:}&\mathbf {\text{end procedure}}\\
\hline
&\end{array}
$$

Python ([test with codepad](http://codepad.org/BJZXIWqv)):

```python
#https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11418/2755

def F(a):
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(n):
        assert a[i] >= 0

    # (r) => coefficient
    # coefficient \cdot x^{r}
    S = {}
    for ai in a:
        for aj in a:
            r = ai + aj

            if r not in S:
                S[r] = 0

            S[r] += 1

    return list(S.items())

def SQUARE(x):
    x = int(x)

    a = []
    i = 0
    while x != 0:
        if x & 1 == 1:
            a += [i]
        x >>= 1
        i += 1

    print 'a:',a
    P2 = F(a)

    print 'P^2:',P2

    s = 0
    for e,c in P2:
        s += (1 << e)*c
    return s
```

**3.** **Thus, squaring is at most as hard as this problem.**

**4.** **Therefore, integer squaring is equivalent to this problem.** (they are each at most as hard as each-other, due to (**2**,**3**,**1**))

Now it is unknown if integer/polynomial multiplication admits bounds better than $\mathcal O(n\log n)$; in fact the best multiplication algorithms currently all use FFT and have run-times like $\mathcal O(n \log n \log \log n)$ ([Schönhage-Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage-Strassen_algorithm)) and $\mathcal O\left(n \log n\,2^{\mathcal O(\log^* n)}\right)$ ([Fürer's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrer%27s_algorithm)). Arnold Schönhage and Volker Strassen conjectured a lower bound of $\Omega\left(n \log n\right)$, and so far this seems to be holding.

This doesn't mean your use of FFT is quicker; $\mathcal O\left(n\log n\right)$ for FFT is the number of operations (I think), not the bit complexity; hence it ignores some factors of smaller multiplications; when used recursively, it would become closer to the FFT multiplication algorithms listed above (see [Where is the mistake in this apparently-O(n lg n) multiplication algorithm?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9034/2755)).

**5.** Now, your problem is not exactly multiplication, it is squaring. **So is squaring easier? Well, it is an open problem (no for now)**: squaring is not known to have a faster algorithm than multiplication. If you could find a better algorithm for your problem than using multiplication; then this would likely be a breakthrough.

So as of now, the answer to both your questions is: **no**, as of now, all the ~$\mathcal O(n\log n)$ multiplication algorithms use FFT; and as of now squaring is as hard as multiplication. And **no**, unless a faster algorithm for squaring is found, or multiplication breaks the $\mathcal O(n\log n)$ barrier, your problem cannot be solved faster than $\mathcal O(n \log n)$; in fact, it cannot currently be solved in $\mathcal O(n\log n)$ either, as the best multiplication algorithm only approaches that complexity.